# Keyboard Shortcuts Phrases

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, settings, shortcut

Does iCloud push the "keyboard shortcuts phrases" between the iOS and macOS devices?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you have "Documents & Data" checked on iCloud preferences on OS X (since 10.9).